# Conditional Formatting in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

Good day,

I'm trying to make an efficient conditional formatting work in Microsoft Word with an VBA, that will be very similar to the formatting known from Excel.

**My current solution**

[image]

I have a 4th column with an IF statement in a field that checks if the value in Column 2 is less equal or higher than in Column 3, combined with this VBA for conditional formatting:

```
Sub UBC()
    color "No", wdRed
    color "Yes", wdBrightGreen
End Sub

Function color(text As String, backgroundColor As WdColorIndex)
    Dim r As Word.Range

    Set r = ActiveDocument.Content

    With r.Find
       Do While .Execute(findText:=text, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
          If r.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            If r.Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 4 Then
                r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor
            End If
          End If
       Loop
    End With
End Function
```

**The result I want to achieve**

[image]

I want to eliminate the 4th column and use the VBA to do the check what's now handled by the IF statement. On top of that, I would also like to use RGB or HEX color codes instead of the wdColorIndex library.

Can somebody help me out modifying the current code?

Comment: Seems like you'd need to start by identifying the table(s) you need to apply the formatting to, then loop over the rows off each table and check the values of the second and third cells in each row, and apply the formatting based on the result.  Have you attempted any of that?

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html#post47254 and *Conditionally Shade Table Cells* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: @macropod I've analyzed a lot of your great codes in the internet, but I haven't found one that would fit to this particular occasion (without using IF in the field) that compares values of two columns. I fear the VBA presented in my post needs to be rewritten entirely from the scratch

Comment: @TimWilliams There will be only one table in this file. The other things you mentioned were the things that I was looking for how to do, but never found anything applicable for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim tbl As Table, rw As Row, v1, v2
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        v1 = CellValue(rw.Cells(2))
        v2 = CellValue(rw.Cells(3))
        If IsNumeric(v1) And IsNumeric(v2) Then
            v1 = CDbl(v1)
            v2 = CDbl(v2)
            Debug.Print v1, v2
            rw.Cells(2).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = _
                     IIf(v1 <= v2, RGB(100, 250, 100), RGB(250, 100, 100))
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

Function CellValue(c As Cell)
    Dim rv
    rv = c.Range.Text
    CellValue = Left(rv, Len(rv) - 2) 'remove "end of cell" marker
End Function
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, works exactly as expected, also explains me a lot coding for the future. Thank you